# Dplyr: Subset numbered Variables easy

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe with Variables with numbered names like `'dtx1', 'dtx2' (...) 'dtx20'`. I want to select a subset with 'dplyr'. How can I choose all of the variables? I don't want to write out every name:
`new_df <- select(old_df, dtx1, dtx2, (...), dtx20)`
I've tried multiple searches here and on google but I may not have the right vokabulary.

Comment: `select(old_df, starts_with("dtx"))`

Answer (score 0):

If you know from where to where you want to subset you can use something like this:

```
DF <- dplyr::select(DF, -c(dtxN:dtxM))` #Being N and M the numbers.
```

If you dont know wich are the ones that you want to eliminate but you they all have a part of the name in common, borrowing from @Mateusz1981:

```
DF <- DF[,- grep("dtx",colnames))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say we have a dummy data frame `old_df`:

```
  dtx1 dtx20 dtx d1tx
1    0     0   0    1
2    1     2   0    2
```

If you'd only like to keep columns that are numbered at the end of the string, you could do this with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

new_df <- select(old_df, matches("[0-9]+$"))
```

Output:

```
  dtx1 dtx20
1    0     0
2    1     2
```

It basically matches any kind of number at the end of the column names.

Comment: Thank you! I used more specified: new_df <- select(old_df, matches("dtx[0-9]+$"))

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `contains` if you want all variables that contains a certain string:

```
new_df = old_df %>% 
    select(contains("dtx"))
```

Answer (score 0):

`dplyr::num_range()` might be a good choice, along with `dplyr::starts_with()` depending on what you want to keep exactly.

```
df1 <- data.frame(foo=1,dtx1 = 2, dtx2 = 3, bar = 4, dtx3 = 5, dtx4 = 6)
df1
#   foo dtx1 dtx2 bar dtx3 dtx4
# 1   1    2    3   4    5    6

library(dplyr)

select(df1, num_range("dtx",1:3))
#   dtx1 dtx2 dtx3
# 1    2    3    5

select(df1, starts_with("dtx"))
#   dtx1 dtx2 dtx3 dtx4
# 1    2    3    5    6
```

This is less safe :

```
select(df1, dtx1:dtx4)
#   dtx1 dtx2 bar dtx3 dtx4
# 1    2    3   4    5    6
```